# Display Single Record -- Best practice

Tags: asp.net

To display a single record based on query-string parameter should i use sqldatasource and repeater or HTML Table with labels inside it and assign the value from the code behind.

(This clearly is not about best practices. I have to resort to this method due to time constraint)

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: That question title is terrible. Consider changing it to something that is related to your actual question.

Comment: Use repeater to show a list of records. Here you should use a bounch of simple labels or DetailsView control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a single record, with no chance of more than one, then just use labels - the repeater adds an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 1):

`DetailsView` (+ `DataSource`) can print out a table of name-value pairs.

Personally i prefer manual table with `Label`s and `Literal`s.